# git on Mac sees files I havent touched as modified and they also appear as staged already

Tags: windows, git, macos

I am seeing strange behavior on Mac with git.  I dont see this happening on Windows.  Using git v 2.19.1 on mac and 2.18.0.windows.1 on windows.

I work in a crossplatform team, so some of us use Windows, others use Mac.  I use both.

Here is the scenario I see:

I work on my feature branch for few days and like to make sure I update my branch with latest changes on remote so I always work on most recent version of remote.  So, I daily do following to reduce chance of conflicts and stay on most recent version:

```
git checkout develop
git fetch origin
git merge origin/develop 
git checkout my-feature
git merge develop
```

Once that is done, I apply my changes to my-feature branch but I notice that git behaves very strangely on Mac.  Here is what happens:

- I added some changes
- I did not stage anything yet, **so no `git add .` was issued**
- I do `git status` and I see lots of files as if they got modified and staged by me even though I did neither modified nor staged them.

For example, git status shows my .gitignore file now as:

```
me$ git status
On branch my-feature
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/my-feature'.

Changes to be committed:
  new file:  .gitignore
```

On Windows, this does not happen and since I did not modify this file, it will not show in `git status` at all.  My modified files show as needed to be added which is how it should behave.

Why would files I never touched be viewed by git on Mac as somehow modified and staged?

Comment: I think there's a broken Git distribution for MacOS out in the wild, as many people are reporting bizarre bugs. They all seem to share a common bit of behavior, in that the index (aka "staging area") is getting corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

In mixed dev environments (like I work in also) I see this behavior when 'line endings' are mismatched.  The best way to solve this is to update your `.gitconfig` file.

I encourage everyone on the teams I work within to add the following to their `.gitconfig` file. You can add a `.gitconfig` to each repo, just like a `.gitignore`, and/or each developer can set it within their git global config file.

```
[text]
   eof=lf
```

There are different options, but the key is for the whole team to use the same line endings when committing & pulling.

Here is my gitconfig, per the request below.

```
[User]
    name = Ben Horgen
    email = xxx@xxxxxxxx.com
[text]
    eof=lf
[core]
    autocrlf = input    
[pull]
    rebase = true
[push]
    default = simple
```

Comment: To set eof=lf even on Windows?

Comment: I would encourage yes! Why have two characters represent a line ending when one will do... but of course using 'eof=cflf` is just as effective in solving your problem (if you prefer Windows-style line endings). All modern editors on Windows handle 'linux' style line endings just fine. But in the rear occasion your dev tool on a Windows computer doesn't like it... using 'eof=cflf` is a good option.

Comment: And you work in a mixed dev environment (Mac, Windows) and all of devs on both machines have eof set to LF?  Can you provide your .gitconfig?  Also, can you say with a confidence that before you all used LF, you had the issue I reported above and after you added eof=LF, the issue stopped reoccurring?  The reason I am so careful is that we have teams all over the world and any change like this can cause lots of disturbance.  Thanks again

Comment: I can assure you we had the exact issue. In addition, I personally run both Windows and MacOS on the same laptop (using Parallels on a Macbook). But other engineers are Windows only.  I can confirm this will not affect your engineers if they're using: Notepad++, Visual Studio, VS Code, Atom, and most other popular IDEs/Editors... including Vi. I'll attach my .gitconfig in my answer.